# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I am working on php using codeigniter framework as a beginner. My program is running perfectly on my localhost. But after uploading to the web server, it is showing an error for some pages. I have searched about this problem and most of the solutions show that my program is right. But for the live server, it is showing PHP fatal error. First one is, whenever I want to see data in datatable it is showing HTTP 500 error. My server administrator told me this is because of my model whenever I am returning data as result_array(). Here is my model,

```
 public function get_pages()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('page');
        $this->db->join('NavigationMenu', 'NavigationMenu.MenuID = page.MenuID', 'left');
        $this->db->join('SubMenu', 'SubMenu.SubMenuID = Page.SubMenuID', 'left');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Here is my controller for that,

```
public function pages()
{
        $data['page'] = $this->Pages_Model->get_pages();
        $tempString =  $this->load->view('admin_panel/content/pages', $data, true);
        $page_data = array(
            'fileHere' => $tempString
        );
        $this->load->view('admin_panel/shared/admin_layout',$page_data);
}
```

And this is my View page,

```html
<!-- Main content -->
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title">Page Lists</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-header -->
    <div class="box-body">
        <table id="page_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Main Menu</th>
                  <th>Sub-Menu</th>
                  <th>Edit/Remove</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($page as $page_item): ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $page_item['PageTitle']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $page_item['MenuName']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $page_item['SubMenuName']; ?></td>
                        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="javascipt:window.location.href='<?php echo base_url('content/edit_page_content')?>/<?php echo $page_item['PageID']; ?>'">Edit</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete_page" id="<?php echo $page_item['PageID']; ?>">Remove</button></td></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                <?php endforeach; ?>                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
</div>

<!-- /.content -->
```

This is one of my problem. I beleive if I get a solution I can solve others. The result_array() function is working perfectly in other places like where I need to fetch data. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you put the error line without altering it?

Comment: An error like that indicates your database operation failed for some reason. The reason is usually logged in your error log, so look there first.

Comment: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object in /e/web-std/for-2401/for2401/application/models/Admin_Panel/Pages_Model.php on line 24, referer: http://www.for-2401.de/for2401/index.php/content/navigation_menus
This is the error @Adrian

Comment: Okay, it says it right there, your $query seems to be a non-object. var_dump($query) and check what it prints out. It's basic debugging.

Comment: if `$query` is not an object it means your query failed. Maybe because `$this->db->join('SubMenu', 'SubMenu.SubMenuID = Page.SubMenuID', 'left'); should be `$this->db->join('SubMenu', 'SubMenu.SubMenuID = page.SubMenuID', 'left');`  lowercase in p page.SubMenuID?

Comment: This is showing bool(false). But for other query it is showing the database information correctly. What am I supposed to do for that? @Adrián

Comment: Two things: Check if that specific query is correct and prevent the error with an if or inference.

Comment: Great ! It works ! It is all because of lowercase . Thanks for your suggestion  @DFriend

Answer (score 0):

Try This as controller,

```
public function pages()
        {
                $data['page'] = $this->Pages_Model->get_pages();
                $this->load->view('admin_panel/content/pages',$data);
                $this->load->view('admin_panel/shared/admin_layout',$data);
        }
```

`</pre>`

Comment: Well. I have found the problem. My database is case-sensitive that is why it is showing that error.

Answer (score 0):

My database is case-sensitive. This is the reason it is showing that error. I have modified my model and it works now.

```
public function get_pages()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('Page');
    $this->db->join('NavigationMenu', 'NavigationMenu.MenuID = Page.MenuID', 'left');
    $this->db->join('SubMenu', 'SubMenu.SubMenuID = Page.SubMenuID', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```